# Limited # of tasks run async concurrently in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, asynchronous, ssis, batch-processing

Searching for a proper technology selection, preferably from MS Azure PaaS  (so-called "serverless"), since this ***needs*** to run in Azure.

The problem / conditions:

Running a set of N completely independent tasks, whilst maximum of M tasks simultaneously.

1. Each task's start can be triggered asynchronously (basically it
   is a start of SSIS package), so I don't need to have a blocking
   wait.
2. Limit the number of concurrently progressing tasks (stated above already)
3. I can't subscribe to automatic notification that a task is complete, I can only explicitly query that info outside (from SSISDB - so actually can query-out statuses for all running tasks via a single query)
4. There are some additional requirements like task retries upon failure etc.

Considering relevant parts of this solution can be implemented in .NET,  the idea is not writing the whole system from scratch (even though it could be the easiest),  but use some Azure Cloud capabilities.

So far I've looked into Azure Queues / Service Bus,  Functions, Azure Batches. But e.g. I don't see very good applicability to Bacthes here, since my tasks are async  and they will consume computational resources out of SQL Server (SSIS).  But probably I'm just mistaken and this can be still a good usage scenario for Azure Batches. Could you please advise smth?

Afterall it might not necessarily be an Azure solution, solved via some proper .NET technology / framework, and deployed to Azure as a durable function (or some other serverless approach), but this is less desirable.

Comment: Did you check [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) Hangfire for that?

Answer (score 1):

I would build an SSIS "master package" that calls your SSIS sub-packages.  That can meet all of your requirements:

1. On the Control Flow, create an Execute Package Task for each SSIS sub-package. Leave them unconnected by Precedence Constraints and they will start asynchronously.
2. For the master package, set the property Max Conncurrent Executables: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.maxconcurrentexecutables.aspx
3. Query SSISDB SQL tables for progress e.g. https://github.com/yorek/ssis-queries
4. In the master package, place each Execute Package Task inside a For Loop Container e.g. http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/retry-task-on-failure.html

Comment: Thanks Mike.  This has been very interesting.  Although our # of tasks is constantly extending, and it will add a maintenance of SSIS package modification, this is a worthwhile approach, and we'll consider it.

Comment: Its likely less effort to maintain than any custom-coded solution, and any new dev with basic SSIS skills should pick it up quickly.

Comment: If you have a lot of quick packages with no specific requirements, you can run them in a For Loop container with a single Execute Package Task using Expressions. Execution within the Loop will be serial, but tasks outside the Loop will continue in parallel.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

No sure if it fits perfectly, but you could look into using Service Fabric. You could have your Jobs/Tasks run as Service Fabric Actors which can be managed by a central service.
This would involve a bit more custom code than you probably would like, but you can implement very complex scenarios without having to handle too much of the infrastructure.

I posted a similar solution a while back:

[Service fabric task queue with completion task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386243/service-fabric-task-queue-with-completion-task/46402385#46402385)

Comment: Thanks Alex,   in mentioned regards this looks very similar to Azure Automation Batches, with manual orchestration efforts, and also preserves serverless bit.  We'll look into it.